# Returning MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I want to return the value so on the caller i can use for example asd["columnname"] but im getting one error, example/code below.

**I have this code**

```
public static MySqlDataReader QueryResultadoMultString(string Query)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = Query;
                MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
                        return myReader;
                    }
                }

                return myReader;
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                NAPI.Util.ConsoleOutput($"[BaseDados][Erro] {ex.Message}");

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Below is the caller**

```
var asd = BaseDadosSQL.QueryResultadoMultString($"SELECT `socialclub`,`username`,`password` FROM contas WHERE socialclub = '{player.SocialClubName}'");
Console.WriteLine("Result "+asd["username"]);
```

I'm getting this error

> System.Exception: 'No current query in data reader'

Comment: Don't return the data reader, return the results from the query.

Comment: Why return reader instead of making it void

Comment: DataReader after read method will close immediately and dispose  connections therefor you can't access to values, then set values on a Data Table or an object of generic class

Answer (score 3):

The method as written will force you to write code that is horribly vulnerable to sql injection issues. You need a separate set of arguments for parameters.

You want something more like this (which should also fix the issue in your question):

```
public static class BaseDadosSQL
{
    private static string connectionString = "connection string here";

    public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> QueryResult(string Query, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
        {
            if (parameters is object && parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }

            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return reader;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
//Guessing at type and length here. Use the actual type and length from the database
var p = new MySqlParameter("@SocialClub", MySqlDbType.VarString, 20);
p.Value = player.SocialClubName;
try
{
    var asd = BaseDadosSQL.QueryResult($"SELECT `socialclub`,`username`,`password` FROM contas WHERE socialclub = @SocialClub", p);
    foreach(var result in asd)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result " + result["username"]);
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
   NAPI.Util.ConsoleOutput($"[BaseDados][Erro] {ex.Message}");
}
```

**This code will let you use Social Club names which includes apostrophes.** The original would have blown up. Notice I also moved the exception handling out of the DB code.

Ideally, even the `QueryResult()` method should also be `private`, with the `BaseDadosSQL` class having a separate `public` method for each query you need to run. So it would look more like this:

```
public static class BaseDadosSQL
{
    private static string connectionString = "connection string here";

    private static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> QueryResult(string Query, params MySqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
        {
            if (parameters is object && parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }

            conn.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return reader;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetClubLogin(string clubName)
    {
        //Still guessing at type and length here.
        var p = new MySqlParameter("@SocialClub", MySqlDbType.VarString, 20);
        p.Value = clubName;
        return QueryResult($"SELECT `socialclub`,`username`,`password` FROM contas WHERE socialclub = @SocialClub", p); 
    }
}
```

And then called like this:

```
try
{
    foreach(var result in BaseDadosSQL.GetClubLogin(player.SocialClubName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result " + result["username"]);
    }
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
   NAPI.Util.ConsoleOutput($"[BaseDados][Erro] {ex.Message}");
}
```

Finally, it's really *Really* **REALLY BAD** to store passwords like that. So bad, it's not even okay for testing/learning/proof of concept code. NEVER DO THAT! It's not even okay to store passwords encrypted. *Encryption is not good enough.*

Passwords should only ever be stored as a fixed-length, salted, cryptographic (not-MD5) hash value. When someone tries to login, you salt and hash the attempted credential, and then *compare the hash values*, not the actual password. Anything else is just *begging* to end up on the front page of your newspaper of choice as the latest big data breach.

Comment: `yield return reader;` returning an `IDataRecord` - did not know that. Very neat.